# How to apply transition when using toggleClass('...',false,this.....) - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I am using the `toggleClass` feature to apply and remove a CSS class due to the nature of the class itself containing `:before`, however the code here will be more generic to help others understand the nuts and bolts.

I can have a transition when the class is added to the element, but I can't seem to get one when removing it. Can anybody help?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="container" on-scroll="toggleShadow">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blue {
    transition: all 1s;
        background: blue;
    }

    .container {
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
       overflow: auto;
    }

    .content {
      margin: auto;
      width: 50px;
      height: 800px;
      background: linear-gradient(lightblue, limegreen);

    }
```

**JS (Polymer)**

```
toggleShadow : function(){
 if(scroll >= 2) {
          this.toggleClass('blue',true,this.$.container);
      } else {
          this.toggleClass('blue',false,this.$.container);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe try adding .stop() to stop any previous animations before the toggle call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have the transition effect when .blue is applied, instead place the transition on the .container

```
.blue {
    background: blue;
}

.container {
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Aha! I knew it would be something small that I was missing!
Thanks a lot!